# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore"

Tags: ios, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Please help me to fix that
I added firestore to flutter project and it works fine for android
but for ios I can't run app in simulator

I generated podfile and added

```
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
```

also change platform to

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

but I get error when run this command in terminal 'pod install --repo-update'

```
Error like this:
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "cloud_firestore":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

Dependency in pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_core: ^1.1.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.7
  firebase: ^9.0.1
```

Comment: Have you previously added the line to your Podfile to use the pre-compiled Firestore binary?

Answer (score 1):

you might need to change the platform to a higher iOS version judging from this message given by the terminal  ↓

```
dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

you might want to change the platform to something like iOS 12 or 13, iOS 13 worked best for me.

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```